# Why saturated vapor does not obey gas laws?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, evaporation

in my book it has mentioned "**number of saturate molecules does not remain constant when the temperature changes(mass of vapor is not constant),therefor saturated vapor does not obeys gas law**"
but how can we say like this, in gas law equations number of moles also included right, so by keeping pressure constant and while increasing in temperature the number of moles can decrease right.
so wont the explanation should be regarding attractions and internal volume?

Comment: Gas laws such as Boyle’s law, Charles’s law, and Gay-Lussac’s law assume a constant amount of gas, so they don’t apply when the amount can change. It’s a little hard to interpret the text, as it sounds like it’s been translated from another language.

Comment: @Chemomechanics can we apply ideal gas equation PV=nrt?

Comment: Condensing vapors are NOT ideal gases.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal gas law where R is the specific gas constant and $m$ is the mass of the gas is

$$pV=mRT$$

I think the book is making the following (though IMO poorly worded) point:

A vapor is a gas that is saturated and therefor condenses if there is any heat transferred out of the vapor due to temperature change (decrease). Once such condensation begins, the mass $m$ is no longer that of the gas, but the combination of vapor and liquid. Moreover, intermolecular attractive forces between the liquid molecules cannot be ignored (one requirement for ideal gas behavior) and therefore the ideal gas equation can not be applied.

Hope this helps.